# PHP Comparing time and listing data within

Tags: php, datetime, time, compare

I have the following variables...

```
$pickupDate = $row['pickupDate'];
$pickupTime = $row['pickupTime'];
$dateRetrieve = date("y/m/d");
$currentDate = "20".$dateRetrieve;
$currentTime = date("h:i:sa")
```

I have an SQL table providing the Pickup Date and Time. I would like to compare the current date/time with the ones in the table, and list all the entities within 2 hours of the current date/time.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not `$dateRetrieve = date("Y/m/d");` if you add "20" on the next line anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use As Following

```
    $currenttime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    //DISPLAY CURRENT TIME
    $lasttwohour = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-2 hour'));
    //TWO HOUR AGO TIME

    $query = "select * from tbl_nm where '$pickupTime' between '$currenttime' AND '$lasttwohour' order by id ";
```

Or if you dont have datetime field you can remove ('Y-m-d') from $currenttime and $lasttwohour.

I Hope it might helpful.